# How to print all values by sort in mongodb using node.js and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I am trying to work with node.js and mongodb.

Here is small code from [a website explaining sort in mongodb using node.js.](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Cursor.html#sort)

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
test = require('assert');

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {

// Create a collection
var collection = db.collection('simple_sort_collection');

// Insert some documents we can sort on
collection.insertMany([{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}], {w:1}, function(err, docs) {
test.equal(null, err);

// Do normal ascending sort
collection.find().sort([['a', 1]]).nextObject(function(err, item) {
  console.log(item);

  // Do normal descending sort
  collection.find().sort([['a', -1]]).nextObject(function(err, item) {
    console.log(item);
    db.close();
  });
});
});
});
```

When I run this piece of code I get the following output:

```
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 1 } //ascending

{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa57, a: 3 } //descending
```

But generally when we do a `find()` and `sort()` we get list of all the values in the table in `ascending` or `descending` order.

But here I get only the first value in the `sort` operation.

I want the output to be like this:

```
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 1 } //ascending
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 2 }
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa57, a: 3 }


{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 3 } //descending
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 2 }
{ _id: 566526a6d811e5a81f4bfa55, a: 1 }
```

Can anyone explain what is wrong in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of [`nextObject()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#nextobject), it gets only the next document. To display all documents, use [`toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#toarray):

```
// Do normal ascending sort
collection.find().sort({ a: 1 }).toArray(function (err, items) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log(items);

    // Do normal descending sort
    collection.find().sort({ a: -1 }).toArray(function (err2, items2) {
        if (err2) console.log(err2);
        console.log(items2);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: it is printing `undefined` in the console.

Comment: Because there are errors and the sort syntax is for cursors. I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Error log:  

`{ [MongoError: n/a]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'n/a',
  '$err': 'Can\'t canonicalize query: BadValue bad order array [2]',
  code: 17287 }`

Comment: The sort parameter has changed, you're still using the array syntax.

Comment: Because every time you run your code, it creates the 3 lines again. Look at the _id, they're all different objects. If you want to clean the collection every time, just put `collection.remove();` after the collection declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Because `sort()` return a Cursor object. To iterate over it, you can use `toArray()` or  `each()`

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    test = require('assert');

    MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err, db) {
        // Create a collection
        var collection = db.collection('simple_sort_collection');

        // Insert some documents we can sort on
        collection.insertMany([{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}], {w:1}, function(err, docs) {
            test.equal(null, err);

            // Do normal ascending sort
            collection.find().sort({'a': 1}).each(function(err, item) {
                test.equal(null, err);

                if (item != null) {
                    console.log(item);
                } else {
                    console.log('====================')
                    collection.find().sort({a: -1}).each(function(err, item) {
                        test.equal(null, err);

                        if (item != null) {
                            console.log(item);
                        } else {
                            db.close();
                        }
                    });
                }
           });
       });
  });
```

It's quite similar to `toArray()`, except that`toArray()` iterates completely the cursor and load all the documents in second argument of the callback function.

As with `each()` method, the cursor will only hold a maximum of batch size elements, and iterate again and again until the cursor is exhausted

For demo purpose, you can use any. But in real world apps, i think `each()` is better for performance